# Some clarification on TCB of an operting system

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

I'm a computer undergraduate taking operating systems course. For my assignment, I am required to implement a simple thread management system.

I'm in the process of creating a struct for a TCB. According to my lecture notes, what I could have in my TCB are:

registers, 
program counter,
stack pointer,
thread ID and
process ID

Now according to my lecture notes, each thread should have its own stack. And my problem is this:

Just by storing the stack pointer, can I keep a unique stack per thread? If I did so, won't one stack of a thread over write other's stack?

How can I prevent that? Limit the stack for each thread??? Please tell me how this is usually done in a normal operating system.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The OS may control stack growth by monitoring page faults from inaccessible pages located around the stack portion of the address space. This can help with detection of stack overflows by small amounts.

But if you move the stack pointer way outside the stack region of the address space and use it to access memory, you may step into the global variables or into the heap or the code or another thread's stack and corrupt whatever's there.

Threads run in the same address space for a reason, to share code and data between one another with minimal overhead and their stacks usually aren't excepted from sharing, from being accessible.

The OS is generally unable to do anything about preventing programs from stack overflows and corruptions and helping them to recover from those. The OS simply doesn't and can't know how an arbitrary program works and what it's supposed to do, hence it can't know when things start going wrong and what to do about them. The only thing the OS can do is just terminate a program that's doing something very wrong like trying to access inaccessible resources (memory, system registers, etc) or execute invalid or inaccessible instructions.

Comment: Got your point, thanks.What I'm really asking is, since the OS cannot help me there, what can I do to stop threads from growing their stacks into each others? As I understand, the compiler (C in my case) uses only one stack. So keeping different stack pointers would not keep them from growing into each other.

Comment: When a thread is created, whether its the main thread or any auxiliary thread, it gets its own, separate stack, not overlapping with anything else. Regardless, you can do only so much about preventing bad things from happening.

Comment: Guess I don't have any option other than leaving lots of space between thread stacks.

Comment: Maybe I'd use the heap instead of the stack for thread stacks.

Comment: You may reduce or increase chances of early stack overflow detection by choosing the stack location, but you can't eliminate stack overflows with that.

Comment: Thanks. That's it for me I guess. Thank you very much.